# issue while converting BigDecimal to Integer

Tags: java

I'm facing problem while converting Big Decimal to Integer.
My process description is, First I will be sending List of Integers into a DAO method to validate whether the integers are valid to proceed further. Then the valid List of Integers are processed in another place.

#### Core process

```
List<Integer> payments = DAO.checkStatus(payments); //payments is List of    Integer
if(payments!=null){
    //Do some other operation
    DAO.changeStatus(payments);  //Here payments is List of Integer which we  got from above
```

#### DAO method implementation

1. ```
   checkStatus(List<Integer> payments){
       List<Integer> FinalPayments = null;
       //I have Hibernate query to get the details from Database
       String HQL_Query = "select A.PY from T_Status A where A.status = 4 and  (A.PY=:payments)";
       Query query = session.CreateQuery(HQL_Query);
       FinalPayments = query.list();
       return FinalPayments;
   }
   ```

   In the DataBase PY column is a BigDecimal one. In table its defined as NUMBER. type. While execution of the query i'm getting BigDecimal values for FinalPayments list. There was no error/exception. The BigDecimal value is returned properly.

   In core process, after the 1st method:

   ```
   if(payments!=null){
   //we're doing something with List of Integer payments right?
   //It is passed to 2nd method.
   ```
2. ```
   changeStatus(List<Integer> FinalPayments){
       String HQL_Query="update T_Status A set A.status = 6 where (A.PY:=FinalPayments)";
       Query query = session.CreateQuery(HQL_Query);
       query.setParameter("FinalPayments", FinalPayments);  //Here i'm getting error
       List<Integer> paymentsAfter = query.list();
   }
   ```

   The error is:
   cannot cast java.math.BigDecimal to java.lang.Integer

   Between 1st and 2nd method i tried to convert BigDecimal to Integer. But can't convert Integer list to Integer again.But i need those to be in the format of Integer to process 2nd method. Please help on this..

Comment: You do have a typo here: `List<integer FinalPayments>`  I'm sure you intended for: `List<Integer> FinalPayments`

Comment: The error implies you're trying to do a cast like `(Integer)val` Have you tried using [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue())'s `intValue()` method?

Comment: There's a reason payments are integers. I question why BigDecimal is even involved. Can you not instead change the Database's data type to integer numbers? You won't suffer from data loss that way.

Comment: Yes. ' List<Integer> FinalPayments'  is the right parameter for changeStatus() method.

Comment: @Tyler : Yes. The error was when i tried to convert in b/w 2 methods. But the actual error is hitting on the 2nd method while executing the query

Answer (score 0):

Use the intValue() method on your BigDecimal object to get its int value.

Comment: Implementation please? i'm not getting you

Comment: Firstly, I changed the answer. So read it first. What I mean to say is do this: int myInt = myBigDecimal.intValue();   This will get you the int value of your BigDecimal. For more info, go to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: That too i tried.. But couldn't because the object itself is  list of Integers. And i'm able to put like, Finalpayments.intValue(); in a loop after the 1st method. But in that point also i'm getting error. :(

Comment: Then either use an iterator or use a for loop to convert each element in that list to int and add those converted elements to a new list.

Comment: Thats what i mentioned in the above comments. That didnt work out

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but if you have a BigDecimal and you want a Integer you can use either intValue of intValueExact.

E.g.

```
List<BigDecimal> decimals = ...
List<Integer> ints = decimals.stream().map(BigDecimal::intValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: In which place can i add this? while executing the query itself or outside the method?